# Reverse isekai manga in which the main character retained his powers

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I can't remember the name of the manga where the main character was the weakest of the group that was isekai'd, but when they were sent back to Earth, he was the only one who retained his power/stats. Even though he was the weakest, he was still overpowered by Earth standards. He became like a hero on Earth and was only wearing a knight's helmet as a disguise.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: I think it was already 3 to 4 years ago before pandemic, can't remember what website did I read this, maybe mangakakalot but I can't find it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ***[Ippanjin Enpou Yori Kaeru. Mata Hatara Kaneba!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/fp7pibr/ippanjin-enpou-yori-kaeru-mata-hatara-kaneba)***.

> Shigeru Sugiyama (a cafe assistant), suddenly teleports to a fantasy world, where he realises he is different from the rest. However, this wasn't in a good way. The younger high school students who teleported to the same world had titles of Heroes and [Saints], but Shigeru didn't have any titles to his name. But then it happened again. Shigeru teleported once more, but this time, to the real world!

The main character, Sugiyama Shigeru, a 20-year-old Japanese café assistant, is summoned to another world along with five high school students. They're each granted powers, although Shigeru considered himself to be the weakest of the group.

After three years of adventuring with the others, he's abruptly transported back to Japan alone, retaining both his powers and his gear, including a knight's helmet. He immediately gets into a fight with a bunch of gangsters and completely steamrolls them.

This manga was published in 2020.

[image: Ippanjin Enpou Yori Kaeru. Mata Hatara Kaneba!, chapter 1 page 30.]

[image: Ippanjin Enpou Yori Kaeru. Mata Hatara Kaneba!, chapter 2 page 11.]

Comment: This is it!! thank you so much!!  been looking for this like a month already 